# Talend : Error (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError) when trying to create an Excel file with Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi, talend

I need to create some custom Excel file, and want to do it with Talend. So, I installed the Jar files into a new library :

[image]

But, when I try to test a simple creation with a `tJava`, I encounter this error message:

```
Démarrage du job testExcel a 11:52 22/08/2017.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3778
[statistics] connected
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook
    at projet1.testexcel_0_1.testExcel.tJava_1Process(testExcel.java:303)
    at projet1.testexcel_0_1.testExcel.runJobInTOS(testExcel.java:568)
    at projet1.testexcel_0_1.testExcel.main(testExcel.java:425)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
[statistics] disconnected
Job testExcel terminé à 11:52 22/08/2017. [Code sortie=1]
```

My test code is:

```
HSSFWorkbook xb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet feuilleX = xb.createSheet("new sheet");   
try {

            FileOutputStream fileOutXlsx = new FileOutputStream("d:\\FLUX DECISIONNEL\\Test_Excel.xls");
            xb.write(fileOutXlsx);
            xb.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And my imports are :

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException ;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook ;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet ;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thx u all of you. The 2 ways work perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to import all the jars with one tLibraryLoad. What you can do is, write your excel code in Routine and right click on it and select "edit Routines Libraries". here you can load all your required library. Now you can call this routine in your job.

Answer (score 2):

First Use tLibraryLoad Component to load the required jars in your job then onComponentOK run the tJava with required imports.

Comment: Thx u very much, it seems to work. But i need to import 5 jars, so i make 5 tlibraryload befor the tJava. Is it possible to import all the jars with only one tLibraryLoad ? thx u again Pooja

Comment: Glad to help @Manufr. But one tLibraryLoad loads only one jar, so you have to use five tLibraryLoad to load five jar. For Modulation purpose you can create one separate subjob to load all the libraries then and connect it via tRun component on subjob ok, run your custom code(tJava).

Comment: [This](https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/How-to-include-multiple-runtime-JAR-files-with-a-Job/ta-p/49652) seems to suggest you can load multiple JARs with a single tLibraryLoad via its "Advanced settings"--though I haven't been able to get it to work.